# MIPS assembler change array

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.data

   array:   .word 14, 6, 18, 13, 17

   anzahl:   .word 5

.text

.globl main

   main:   la $t0, array 

      la $t1, anzahl   

      lw $t1, 0($t1)   

      addi $t1, $t1, -2   

      lw $v0, 0($t0)

   loop:   addi $t0, $t0, 4

      lw $t2, 0($t0)

      bge $t2, $v0, skip

      add $v0, $zero, $t2

   skip:   addi $t1, $t1, -1

      bge $t1, $zero, loop
```

Kann jemand den code lesen ?

Ich check nich genau was 0($t1) macht, muss den Wert $v0 bestimmen.

Ich dachte zuerst, das in $t1 das array mit den 5 Werten geladen wird mit lw $t1, 0($t1), verstehe dann aber nich addi $t1, $t1, -2, was genau wird da nun abgezogen, verschwinden nun 2 Elemente im Array oderwas.

Anyone can read this code?
I don't understand what 0($t1) does, i have to find out what value $v0 has, at the end of the program.

First i thought, the array gets loaded into $t1, via lw $t1, 0($t1)

But then i dont understand addi $t1, $t1, -2. Does that mean 2 elements less are in the array now ?

Answer (score 0):

Every MIPS32 instruction is documented in the document *MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set*, which you should get if you're doing any MIPS32 assembly programming.

---

> First i thought, the array gets loaded into $t1, via lw $t1, 0($t1)

No, it loads the value 5 from `anzahl` into `$t1`.

---

> i dont understand addi $t1, $t1, -2. Does that mean 2 elements less are in the array now ?

It has no effect at all on the array. It just subtracts 2 from `$t1`, which appears to contain a loop counter.

Comment: Thank you.Ok and lw $v0, 0($t0) means "v0 = 14" ?

Comment: Hmm, but $v0 never changes after that, so how is the correct answer then "v0=6" ?

Comment: Sure it changes: `add $v0, $zero, $t2`

Comment: last question, $t0 is the adress of the array. But then what does addi $t0, $t0, 4 do ? It changes the adress.

Comment: The size of each element in the array is one _word_ (4 bytes), so adding 4 to the address moves to the next element.

Comment: Thanks, now i got it.